# PHP Stops after first Iteration - <Audio> error

Tags: php, html

I have created a php loop to go through each file in a folder called 'music'. I want this loop to create an HTML5 audio element for each file it finds. Using this code, it will display the first music file, and the audio controls will display but they won't work. I believe that the reason the loop is only iterating once is because of the audio element error. I have tried to print out what the complete path of music/$file looks like, and it seems correct. Any ideas?

```
$files = scandir('music/');
foreach($files as $file) {
 echo pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
 echo '<br>';
 echo '<audio controls src="music/'.$file.'">';
}
```

Comment: can you make it work for one of your files with no `foreach`?

Comment: any issue with the html wont stop a php loop

Comment: HTML errors will not stop a PHP loop. Try closing the audio tag. Maybe the browser is only parsing the first one looking for the close tag.

Comment: Have you tried this [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php)

Comment: For reference: [MDN audio tag page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)